# Javascript doesn't work in django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I have a template which inherits from a base template in javascript.

Here is the base template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    {% include 'base/css.html' %}
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}

  </head>

  <body id="page-top">

    {% include 'base/navbar.html' %}

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    {% include 'base/js.html' %}
    {% block js %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the template where the javascript doesn't work:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block head %}
<link href="{% static 'css/card.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"></link>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="card-wrapper">
    {% for account in object_list %}
    <div id="make-3D-space">
        <div id="product-card">
            <div id="product-front">
                <div class="shadow"></div>
                <img src="" alt="" />
                <div class="image_overlay"></div>
                <div id="view_details"><a href="{{ account.get_absolute_url }}">View details</a></div>
                <div class="stats">         
                    <div class="stats-container">
                        <span class="product_price">{{ account.price }}</span>
                        <span class="product_name">{{ account.get_arena_readable }}</span>    
                        <p>King level {{ account.king_tower }}</p>                                            

                        <div class="product-options">
                            <strong>SIZES</strong>
                            <span>XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</span>
                            <strong>COLORS</strong>
                            <div class="colors">
                                <div class="c-blue"><span></span></div>
                                <div class="c-red"><span></span></div>
                                <div class="c-white"><span></span></div>
                                <div class="c-green"><span></span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
<script src="{% static 'js/card.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock js %}
```

The css loads fine, however the javascript doesn't. I have put the javascript tag in the correct block so the contents of the file should be loaded when I run the local development server. Why does none of the javascript get included?

It appears to be include since card.js is present. [image]

Comment: can you add your settings? where you configure your static path

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_local'),
]`

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn', 'static_root')`

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`
`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn', 'media_root')`

Answer (score 0):

Also in your base.html you have {% block js %}{% endblock %}  but in the second template you have {% block js %}{% endblock js %}.

Comment: src has nothing to do with `card.js`, it's a seperated directory

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access static files from `static` directory as described here:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/card.js' %}"></script>
```

Whereas in your settings you have named the static directory `static_local`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_local'),
]
```

So based on this image:

[image]

The name of your static directory is `static`.
So in your `settings.STATICFILES_DIRS`, replace `static_local` with `static` like the following:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

Comment: But if this was the problem, wouldn't the css also not load? since its in the same static directory, yet it does.

Comment: can you take a look at your console, to see whether django finds the static files well